# How can I toggle a boolean based on keyboard input?

Tags: python, boolean, toggle, keyboard-events, pyautogui

So, I'm trying to create a simple autoclicker in python, just for fun. I've downloaded and experimented with two libraries, PYAutoGUI and Keyboard. I can turn on the autoclicker, but can't turn it off. I want to make it so that whenever I press the key on my keyboard, it toggles the autoclicker from on to off or vice versa. For some reason, it doesn't do this. Is there something I'm missing or am I just a newbie at python? Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

shouldClick = False
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
        shouldClick = not shouldClick
    if shouldClick == True:
        pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: I have not used either of the libraries, but in similar cases, it is often necessary to add a delay between each cycle of the loop, allowing it to actually update when you send your keypress.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but still no luck. I think I'm misunderstanding how to use the keyboard library. Thanks for your advice though, I'll remember that for when I'm using loops in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my answer to my own question:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

shouldClick = False
keyRelease = True

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('z') and keyRelease:
        keyRelease = False
        shouldClick = not shouldClick
    if not keyboard.is_pressed('z'):
        keyRelease = True
    if shouldClick:
        pyautogui.click()
```

Yes, I do tend to ask questions and then figure out the answers myself. It seems I just had to add in a boolean that checks whether I'd pressed the key that instance.

Comment: It is encouraged to answer your own questions, so keep up the good work :)